# find -exec mv stops after first exec

Tags: find

While researching for this question: [Find and move directories based on file type and date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/find-and-move-directories-based-on-file-type-and-date), I stumbled upon a problem of my own.

First I created a bunch of directories with files in them:

```
seq 10 | while read dir; do
  mkdir dir$dir
  touch dir$dir/file.txt
  seq 5 | while read file; do
    touch dir$dir/file${dir}_$file
  done
done
```

Then I tried following find command:

```
$ find -type f -name "*.txt"
./dir6/file.txt
./dir8/file.txt
./dir10/file.txt
...
```

Works as expected.

Now with an `-exec`:

```
$ find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'echo mv -v "${0%/*}" ../bar' {} \;
mv -v ./dir6 ../bar
mv -v ./dir8 ../bar
mv -v ./dir10 ../bar
...
```

Works as expected.

Now the actual command:

```
$ find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'mv -v "${0%/*}" ../bar' {} \;
`./dir6' -> `../bar/dir6'
```

It stops after the first `mv`. No error message. Exit status is 0. The directory `bar` exists and `dir6` is moved correctly.

When I execute again this happens:

```
$ find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'mv -v "${0%/*}" ../bar' {} \;
`./dir8' -> `../bar/dir8'
```

Again stop after the first `mv`. Exit status is 0. `dir8` is moved correctly.

Why does `find` stop after the first `mv`? Because the directory is moved and `find` is confused? Why does it not print an error or return an error exit status?

When I create more directories and more files it has the same behaviour.

In the question linked above the problem is that `find` executes once without problem but print errors for all matches after that. Is this related?

Using `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In:

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'mv -v "${0%/*}" ../bar' {} \;
```

`find` opens the current directory (`.`), gets the content (`list1`). Then goes on to process that list. It processes `dir6`; as that file is a directory, it chdirs into it, opens it gets a second list of files (`list2`), processes `file.txt` and does:

```
mv -v ./dir6 ../bar
```

Now, `find`'s current directory has not changed, but its path has changed: it is now `../bar/dir6`. After finishing traversing the content of `dir6`, it goes back up (`chdir("..")`) and is now in `../bar`. [`find` detects that the directory is not the same as before and exits](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/fts.c?id=9fc81090f6c5590bd1b0e0fa5087577a2ee43a3e#n2066).

Comment: I suspected something like that. But why does it not find `dir6` after moving `dir8` in the second invocation?

Comment: Good point, I've done some research and updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a bug then, to exit with status 0 in such a case.